# iOS MapKit -search location type

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Do you have any idea how to get that string **"Country - Asia"** under "Thailand" from a search result in MapKit?

I've looked into `MKLocalSearchCompleter` and all the related classes. But I didn't find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MKLocalSearchCompleter has a property named ***results***, which is an array of MKLocalSearchCompletion. This type has a property named subtitle, which is what you may be looking for.

You can try something like this:

```
let completer: MKLocationSearchCompleter = yourCompleter
let subtitle: String = completer.results.first?.subtitle
```

More on this subject: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompletion

Comment: nope, it is not

Comment: my bad :/ could you detail more how that search is working? Or is that image an inspiration to what you're doing?